# In a sorted array a, if a[0] is larger than 0, no other value can equal its index right?

Tags: arrays, sorting, search

If I have a sorted (strictly increasing) array where a[0] != 0, and a[0] < a[1], then no other value exists that can equal its value right?
So other than 0, a[i] != i ?

edit: wrong operator

Comment: There are also no repeats allowed!

Comment: No, it's not true. Counterexample: `[1, 1.5, 2]`

Comment: It was in space N I was talking about, should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you have an (ascending) sorted array with positive integers only, no dublicates. If a[0]>0 then for all i: a[i]>i. This is true, proof trough induction:

Init:

for i=0, this is trivial.

Step:

assume the condition holds for i (a[i]>i), prove it holds for i+1 (a[i+1]>i+1):

- a[i+1] > a[i] > i
- a[i+1] > a[i] >= i+1
- a[i+1] > i+1

qed.

Comment: Great! Thank you !